# Mozilla sunbird : Multi-day event looks weird in calendar

Tags: google-calendar, lightning

I'm testing the Mozilla calendar, Sunbird.

I've added a 4-days event, but I find that it looks a little weird, compared to what it looks like in google calendar :

*Sunbird*

[image: a 4 days event in sunbird]

*Google Calendar*

[image: a 4-days event in Google calendar]

Is there an option to have the long events span multiple cells ?

Comment: I'd like to be able to change this too! It obviously also affects Lightning

Comment: I'm also still looking for something working on Lightning. There is nothing, also no addon, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that in the current version.

This was a feature request that languished a while (since 2003): [Events spanning days are seen as multiple events (display)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199732), and was then watered down into this: [Add markers for multi-day events in multiday views](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449908)

The watered-down requirement was to have made the 0.9 release according to the [Sunbird 0.9 release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/releases/sunbird0.9.html),

```
* Events spanning days now have a visual indicator indicating them as connected events
* When reloading a remote calendar a progress indicator is now shown
* The so-called "minimonth" (small calendar month in the upper left) has been given a visual overhaul
* The calendar views (day, week, multiweek, month) have been given a visual overhaul
* CalDAV support and interoperability with various CalDAV servers has been improved
* The application stability and memory consumption has been greatly improved
* A full list of changes that have gone into this release can be found on The Rumbling Edge website
```

but I don't see the visual indicators either on the Sunbird 0.9 version on Ubuntu.

It is in the Sunbird [UI mockups](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:Calendar_View) so it definitely is on their radar. Going by past history alone, I wouldn't expect to see this feature anytime soon.

Comment: "Going by past history alone, I wouldn't expect to see this feature anytime soon." They don't update very often ?

Comment: No, due to a combination of factors: 1. They are mainly a volunteer project strapped for resources, 2. This is a usability feature, not a functional requirement, 3. This request has already languished for some time, so clearly not urgent, 4. From the initial bug report the solution appears to be non-trivial.

Comment: Sadly, the request is still soldiering on unloved, though it's now at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256588